# What (precisely) is a command?

Tags: terminology, imperative-programming

Which of the following is most appropriately called a "command," and what should the other be called?

1. `changeDirectoryTo`
2. `changeDirectoryTo /home/peter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command is `changeDirectoryTo`. `/home/peter` is the **argument** to that command

Comment: Is there a term for the whole string "changeDirectoryTo /home/peter"?

Comment: It would typically just be referred to as a command, even though there's an argument to it.

Comment: Could the 2 together be called a "statement"?

Comment: Yes, they could be, but command tends to be the most common term. For example, in a terminal window you have a command line, and people refer to things like `ls` or `cd` as commands. The fact that they make take zero or more arguments doesn't alter the fact that they're referred to as commands.